# class destructor segmentation fault

Tags: c++, destructor

WHy does this code cause segmentation fault?
It causes seg fault in destructor.
But when I call the free function without destructor, it's ok.
Some answers does not understand the problem.
The problem is that If I use the free function in the main()
s.free(); 
It works fine.. 
But I make the destructor do the free() job, it is not OK.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Stack
{
public:
    int pop() {
        data = next->data;
        auto tmp = next;
        next = next->next;
        delete tmp;
        return data;
    }
    void push(int n) {
        Stack* p = new Stack();
        p->data = n;
        p->next = next;
        next = p;
        size++;
    }
    virtual ~Stack() {
        free();
    }
    void free() {
        while(next) pop();
    }
    Stack* next = nullptr;

protected:
    int data;
    int size = 0;
};
int main()
{
    Stack s;
    for(int i=0; i<30; i++) s.push(i);
}
```

Comment: I suggest learning to use a debugger.

Comment: You have multiple freeings... As you created many `Stack`s as you push elements, when the initial stack is destroyed, you delete others but chaining remains...

Comment: but the problem is that If I use the free function in the main() s.free(); It works fine.. But I make the destructor do the free() job, it is not OK.

Comment: @Parker, `delete`ing a pointer twice is undefined behavior. By it's very nature, it can either seem to work or crash & burn horribly. That's why we try very hard to write code without UB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `pop` function destroys the entire stack. It `deletes` the `tmp` node (by calling the `Stack` destructor), which still points to the new `next`.
And since the `Stack` destructor calls delete on `next`, you get a mess of multiple destructor calls on the same objects.

**JMA** beat me to it by a few seconds, so refer to their code fix for a quick solution.

However, I would recommend you add a dedicated `Node` struct instead of composing `Stacks`, it will actually increase the clarity of your code.

Comment: What are you talking about? next = next->next; Can't you see that?

Comment: @Parker, mind your manners and fire up a debugger. What does `tmp->next` point to?

Comment: Sorry you were right.. I didn't notice the delete will call destructor. It is different from malloc..

Answer (score -1):

In the constructor of the class you must set `next = nullptr`, otherwhise the loop in the `free()` function won't stop.
Edit:
I think the problem is because on the pop you delete, and that calls the destructor again.
try this one:
`

```
int pop() {
    data = next->data;
    auto tmp = next;
    next = next->next;
    tmp->next = nullptr;
    delete tmp;
    return data;
}
```

`

Comment: He does provide a default value, using c++11 features.